# Exporting entire world from blender to unreal without exporting same asset multiple times

Tags: export, file-format, unreal-engine

Imagine i have a "world" with a proceduraly generated terrain and a proceduraly generated forest (blender script), using only one tree model but placing it a 100 times with random placement, scale, and rotation.

Now want to export this to unreal, preferably as a single file with both terrain and trees. However i don't want unreal to load each tree as a single/individual mesh, but rather one tree mesh, and that the file contains placement coordinates, scale, and rotation. Is this possible? Is there any 3d format that both both Blender and Unreal supports that could do this?

A single fbx bulk export creates one file and is easy to import but it creates one mesh for each tree (all 100) in unreal? or am i missing some setting?

I understand this question overlaps with Unreal knowledge.

I'm preferably looking for a solution that is as universal as possible, that works with other game engines / simulators as well. Otherwise just exporting coord, rotation, and scale for each tree and then importing using a handcrafted unreal script is the solution we are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with this, so I am going to give you an answer that is a basic starting point.  If you haven't already you should download an add on from Epic Games called "Pipeline: Send to Unreal".  In this add on there are some options about "exporting collections" and "combining child meshes", as well as various FBX related controls.   Further research into these settings should help to answer your question more.

https://epicgames.github.io/BlenderTools/send2ue/quickstart.html